# Motherboard continuous short beeps

Tags: motherboard, troubleshooting

I have a system unit that was working perfectly fine last week. I put it into my small internet cafe and days later it wont turn on. The beeps are short continuous beeps which only stops after it restarts on its own. Here is the [video](https://youtu.be/AWPgwMwDrqE)

I tried:
Reseating rams
reset cmos
tried only 1 ram in first slot
tried only 1 ram in second slot
tried no ram(still the same beep)
reseating cpu

specs:
pentium g620
gigabyte ga-h61m-ds2
8gb ram(4x2)

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: It's a RAM issue.

Comment: @DavidPostill can you please elaborate more. i tried one working ram and its still not working

Comment: @DavidPostill same beeps even with known working RAM

Comment: Take it to a repair shop then.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thank you for the great suggestion,  that didn't really crossed my mind.